# C# LoadFont stock

Tags: c#

I have this code for loading custom font from resources:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Text;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadFonts();    
}
PrivateFontCollection LoadFont = new PrivateFontCollection();

    private void LoadFonts()
    {
        Stream fontStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("embedded_font.osb.ttf");
        System.IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)fontStream.Length);
        byte[] fontdata = new byte[fontStream.Length];
        fontStream.Read(fontdata, 0, (int)fontStream.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, data, (int)fontStream.Length);
        LoadFont.AddMemoryFont(data, (int)fontStream.Length);
        fontStream.Close();
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data);
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Font = new Font(LoadFont.Families[0], 9, FontStyle.Bold);
        label1.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
    }
```

It's ok, works nice, but I wan't to load two fonts, how can I do it? For example I have osb.ttf and os.ttf. What's next? Thanks in advace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would break it out into a separate function:

```
    private void LoadFontFromResourcesByName(string FontName)
    {
        Stream fontStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(FontName);
        System.IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)fontStream.Length);
        byte[] fontdata = new byte[fontStream.Length];
        fontStream.Read(fontdata, 0, (int)fontStream.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, data, (int)fontStream.Length);
        LoadFont.AddMemoryFont(data, (int)fontStream.Length);
        fontStream.Close();
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data);
    }

    private void LoadFonts()
    {
        LoadFontFromResourcesByName("embedded_font.osb.ttf");
        LoadFontFromResourcesByName("embedded_font.os.ttf");
    }
```

This is simple refactoring and is a skill you should pick up on. Generalize functions as much as possible to be able to use them differently or repeatedly from other places.

You may also want to safeguard your loading code from creating memory leaks if there is an error in loading the font. Normally I'd say wrap the `fontStream` inside a `using` but that won't clean up unmanaged resources.

Here is how I would do it:

```
        private void LoadFontFromResourcesByName(string FontName)
        {
            using (Stream fontStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(FontName))
            {
                System.IntPtr data = System.IntPtr.Zero;
                try
                {
                    data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)fontStream.Length);
                    byte[] fontdata = new byte[fontStream.Length];
                    fontStream.Read(fontdata, 0, (int)fontStream.Length);
                    Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, data, (int)fontStream.Length);
                    LoadFont.AddMemoryFont(data, (int)fontStream.Length);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (data != System.IntPtr.Zero)
                        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok, thans, how can i use it now? :/

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you use it just like I posted it, add the new function into your form class and replace your existing `LoadFonts` with the one I posted.

Comment: I'm mean how to use this fond? Not I'm using smth like this label1.Font = new Font(LoadFont.Families[0], 9, FontStyle.Bold); how can i use with your function? etc...

Comment: The second one would be at the second index, aka `LoadFont.Families[1]`, etc for each one you load.

Comment: Freeing the unmanaged memory in the `Finalize` part of the Try-Catch block, did the trick for mee.